# JavaMail doesn't send mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I've configured JavaMail inside a java website to send emails using my gmail account through SMTP with TLS (port 587), I've set up the 'gmail less secure apps' to Enable and it works from my PC, the problem is that it doesn't work from a different server and I'm getting this exception:

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14

as I said before I've set up the 'gmail less secure apps' to Enable so that's not the problem, and I've checked and I can connect to smtp.gmail.com with port 587 using telnet so that's not seems to be the problem either.

does anyone have any thoughts? do I need to set up the 'gmail less secure apps' to Enable in every host I'm using..?

Comment: IF this is going to be a universally used email sender, I would consider looking into making it a webservice, then you can add the service reference to each app that needs to use it and only one server will be running the web service.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show for the failure?

Comment: @RyanWilson
I did not get what your saying, Its a "contact us" page inside a website and I'm using JavaMail API to send from my email to itslef the user inputs.

Comment: @BillShannon I cant see debug output because the exception above is thrown before i have the chance to see the log, my code is like this: 
`Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() { protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { return new PasswordAuthentication(emailSettings.get("sender"), emailSettings.get("password")); } }); 

session.setDebug(true);`

Comment: @FLATeric It sounded like you were worried about granting access on different hosts to use the email so I suggested hosting a webservice which handles connecting to the smtp and you can call out to that from any or all applications you develop, then you only have to worry about access on the one host.

Answer (score 0):

I saw @Mate Šimović answering that:

Go to https://g.co/allowaccess from a different device you have previously used to access your Google account and follow the instructions. Try signing in again from the blocked app.

and it works!